# MySQL pivot table in 1 to n relationship

Tags: mysql, join

I have data like this
table master_item

```
+-------+---------+
|item_id|item_name|
+-------+---------+
|  001  |  Car A  |
|  002  |  Car B  |
+-------+---------+
```

and relation into table process

```
+-------+--------+
|proc_id|proc_seq|
+-------+--------+
|  001  |   1    |
|  001  |   2    |
|  001  |   3    |
|  001  |   4    |
|  001  |   5    |
|  002  |   1    |
|  002  |   2    |
|  002  |   3    |
+-------+--------+
```

and i want result like this when i select item_id = 001

```
+-------+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|item_id|item_name|proc1|proc2|proc3|proc4|proc5|proc6|proc7|
+-------+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  001  |  Car A  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |     |     |
+-------+---------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

what is the query to produce this result ?

Comment: Adopt simple query instead of doing this by pivot table query. And do the rest of the work in application level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in `PIVOT TABLE` category.

Here you can accomplish your result through the query given below:

```
SET @sql := '';
SELECT 
CONCAT('SELECT 
MI.item_id,
MI.item_name,',
GROUP_CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN P.proc_seq =', P.proc_seq ,' THEN P.proc_seq END) AS ', 'proc',P.proc_seq,' '),
'FROM master_item MI
INNER JOIN process P ON MI.item_id = P.proc_id
WHERE MI.item_id = 1
GROUP BY P.proc_id') INTO @sql
FROM master_item MI
INNER JOIN process P ON MI.item_id = P.proc_id
WHERE item_id = 1
GROUP BY P.proc_id;


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE stmt;
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f61aa7/1/3)

But like I said, better do this kind of job in application logic. Otherwise it will be too cumbersome to make it done through MySQL alone.

**EDIT:**

In order to get result for each `item_id`

```
SET @sql := '';
SELECT 
CONCAT('SELECT 
MI.item_id,
MI.item_name,',
GROUP_CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN P.proc_seq =', P.proc_seq ,' THEN P.proc_seq END) AS ', 'proc',P.proc_seq,' '),
'FROM master_item MI
INNER JOIN process P ON MI.item_id = P.proc_id
GROUP BY P.proc_id') INTO @sql
FROM master_item MI
INNER JOIN process P ON MI.item_id = P.proc_id

WHERE
    item_id = (
        SELECT
            maxProcId.proc_id
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    proc_id,
                    COUNT(proc_seq) total
                FROM process
                GROUP BY proc_id
                ORDER BY total DESC
                LIMIT 1
            ) AS maxProcId
    )
GROUP BY
    P.proc_id;


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE stmt;
```

<kbd>[**Demonstrated here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f61aa7/5/3)</kbd>

Comment: great but the name and id always 1 and CAR A and process is random

Comment: Didn't you want result for `item_id = 1` only?

Comment: Please run the updated query under edit section. I've made a change there.

Answer (score 0):

With `Group_concat` and then split data to separate column you can do it

```
SELECT t1.*,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t2.proc_seq), ',', 1), ',', -1) AS proc1, 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t2.proc_seq), ',', 2), ',', -1) AS proc2, 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t2.proc_seq), ',', 3), ',', -1) AS proc3, 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t2.proc_seq), ',', 4), ',', -1) AS proc4, 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t2.proc_seq), ',', 5), ',', -1) AS proc5
FROM tt1 t1
LEFT JOIN tt2 t2 ON t1.item_id=t2.proc_id
```

Comment: thx @ashkufaraz for your reply but I want the results are displayed in each column in accordance with the process, not made one in the column proce

Comment: i update my answer, you can do it with sub string_index

Comment: great but the process not accurate when seq is random..must be indexing first